# Conversion rules for overloaded conversion operators

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Given the following code:

```
using System;

namespace Test721
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new A()); //prints 666
            Console.WriteLine(new B()); //prints 666
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public static implicit operator int(A a)
        {
            return 666;
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public static implicit operator double(B b)
        {
            return 667;
        }
    }
}
```

the results are as in the comments - both lines print 666.

I'd expect `Console.WriteLine(new B());` to write 667, while there is a `double` overload of `Console.WriteLine`.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is covered in section 7.4.3.4 of the 3.5 C# language spec.  This section deals in overload resolution and how conversions are considered in this process.  The applicable line is

> If an implicit conversion from T1 to T2 exists, and no implicit conversion from T2 to T1 exists, C1 is the better conversion.

In this case there is an implicit conversion from `B` to both `int` (T1) and `double` (T2).  There is an implicit conversion from `int` to `double` but not the other way around.  Hence the implicit conversion from `B` to `int` is considered better and wins.

Comment: The best answer I could expect, thank you. I'll accept in a minute, when SO allows me to ;]

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that the these rules would make the compiler think an `float` was superior to a `double`?  That would seem pretty brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not specify what to cast the value to the compiler is doing

```
Console.WriteLine((int)(new B()));
```

You should use following instead

```
Console.WriteLine((double)(new B()));
```

Comment: Yes the compiler is doing this but the OP is asking "why" the compiler is doing this.